# Calendar PrimeNG does not work

Tags: angular, primeng

I have installed PrimeNG and want to use Calendar component of it. Thus, I have made a **MyCalendar** Component:

**TS file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-calendar',
  templateUrl: './my-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarDemoComponent  {    
    myDate1: Date;       
}
```

**HTML file:**

```
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <h3> A simple canedar </h3>
      <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDate1"></p-calendar> {{myDate1|date}} // line 4
  </div>
</div>
```

By running the app I get this error on the console:

*CalendarDemoComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute*

Could you please help me finding out what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the **CalendarModule** was missing tn the **App Module**. (I had imported it in **MyCalendar** module).

```
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';    

    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,    
    CalendarModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the name attribute for your calendar,

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDate1" name="date" dateFormat='dd/mm/yy'"></p-calendar>
```